# Diferença de chamadas na main

Tags: c

Pessoal quero saber qual a diferença entre essas duas chamadas?

```
inserir_inicio(&p, cria_no(0));

p = inserir_fim(p, cria_no(0));
```

Quando tento mudar para o estilo da primeira chamada o código compila mas na hora da execução para tudo.

```
//fim
tipo_lista* inserir_fim (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{
//Se a lista estiver vazia
if(p==NULL)
    return novo_no;

tipo_lista* r = p; //Para manter a referencia ao primeiro elemento
while (p->prox != NULL)
{
    p = p->prox;
}
p->prox = novo_no;
return r;
}

//inicio
tipo_lista * inserir_inicio (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{
novo_no -> prox = p;
return novo_no;
}

//main
int main(){
tipo_lista *p = NULL;

//inserir_inicio(&p, cria_no(0));
p = inserir_fim(p, cria_no(0));
p = inserir_inicio(p, cria_no(1));

imprime_lista(p);

return 0
}
```

Obrigado

Comment: Para um resposta precisa, precisamos do código das funções `inserir_inicio` e `inserir_fim`. Apesar de termos quase certeza do problema, sem isso fica difícil dar uma resposta boa de fato.

Comment: @Wilker já adicionei na pergunta as funções que fiz.

Comment: Segundo a definição dessas funções, `inserir_inicio(&p, cria_no(0))` e `p = inserir_fim(p, cria_no(0))` não podem estar ambos certos se se referem à mesma variável `p`. Posta também a `main()`, por favor

Comment: Postei, nota que está comentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No primeiro você está passando o ponteiro para **p**, logo quando você alterar o valor de **p** dentro da função **inserir_inicio**, você altera o valor de **p** fora da função.

Enquanto no segundo você está copiando o valor de uma variável para a variável dentro da função, logo quando você alterar o valor de **p** dentro da função, você não altera o valor de **p** fora da função.

Mis detalhes
https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/pont.html

Comment: E porque da o erro você sabe me dizer?

Comment: Ai precisa colocar mais detalhes, tipo ocorre alguma mensagem de erro ou é congelamento do processo? E só uma instrução não da pra saber o problema.

Comment: Igual disse aí abre o prompt mas da mensagem de programa parou de funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Se for o tipo de coisa que eu estou pensando, a razão é a "emulação de referência". Como você deve saber, as funções em C passam seus parâmetros por valor/cópia. Para emular a passagem por referência, você precisa passar os ponteiros para os parâmetros desejados e trabalhar com esses ponteiros.

Um exemplo meio tosquinho para fixar:

```
void badswap (int a, int b){
   int tmp;

   tmp = a;
   a = b;
   b = tmp;
}

void goodswap (int *ap, int *bp){
   int tmp;

   tmp = *ap;
   *ap = *bp;
   *bp = tmp;
}
```

Para acrescentar-se um elemento ao fim de uma lista encadeada, você passa a cabeça da lista como parâmetro, pois essa cabeça não será modificada. Você só vai modificar a cauda, acrescentando um elemento ao final da mesma.

Já na segunda, para acrescentar-se um elemento à cabeça da lista, efetivamente você tem que modificar a cabeça dessa lista: ela antes estava no local de memória X, agora estará no local de memória Y. Para tanto, você terá que usar a emulação de referência.

Acho que para explicar a causa do erro, eu teria que fazer um teste de mesa, "interpretando mentalmente" o código em si. O meu melhor chute, por ora, é que deve ocorrer alguma confusão de variáveis - imagina como se você tivesse escrito algo como `*tmp = *bp;` no código da `goodswap`. MAS, novamente, para apontar com certeza, eu teria que ver o código completo. Esses erros de segmentation fault são difíceis de explicar de forma "genérica".

*Dica*: se possível, dê uma lida nos *warnings* do compilador. Eles podem conter insights úteis sobre esses erros. Existem também outros softwares, como o *cppcheck*, o *splint* ou mesmo o depurador *gdb*.

#### EDIT:

Cheguei em casa e testei o código modificado no Clang. Pois bem, como eu imaginei, o erro é justamente na passagem de parâmetro.

Primeiramente, a forma com que você fez essas duas funções é diferente da que eu havia pensado, mas é até mais limpa e funcional. Neste sentido, boa parte do meu comentário sobre a emulação de referência é desnecessária.

Segundamente, indo direto ao assunto, eis a mensagem do Clang:

```
testno.c:66:22: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'tipo_lista **' (aka 'struct tipo_lista **') to parameter of type
      'tipo_lista *' (aka 'struct tipo_lista *'); remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  p = inserir_inicio(&p,cria_no(2));
                     ^~
testno.c:37:43: note: passing argument to parameter 'p' here
tipo_lista * inserir_inicio (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
                                          ^
1 warning generated.
```

Com isso, a função espera um ponteiro, mas você está passando um ponteiro-para-o-ponteiro. Não é de se espantar que venha a ter um comportamento errático - se não me engano, de fato isso seria até um caso de *comportamento indefinido*: o compilador está livre para fazer o que bem entender. Por "bem entender", eu quero dizer "qualquer coisa desde disparar mísseis nucleares se houver hardware para isso até derreter o monitor".

MAS, supondo que o compilador traduza isso da forma mais "óbvia" possível, ele simplesmente trata `&p` como se fosse uma posição de memória. "O programador sabe o que está fazendo". Como essa posição de memória não foi legalmente alocada, ela pode estar em qualquer lugar, muito provavelmente em um segmento que não pertence ao programa. E você receberá um belo `SIGSEGV`.

Espero ter ajudado!

*Post Scriptum*: deixei alguns testes enjoados de fora no meu exemplo no IDEONE; por exemplo, se a memoria foi realmente alocada. Mesmo assim, dá para o gasto...

Comment: Sim, suspeito que seja exatamente isto: `p` provavelmente é um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento da lista, e portanto `inserir_inicio()` tem que mudar o valor para o qual `p` aponta dentro de `main()`. Já para `inserir_fim()`, não há necessidade de fazer `p` apontar para outro objeto na memória, então basta passar o endereço a que `p` aponta.

Comment: @Anderson Torres tentas compilar, coloquei as funções na pergunta. Obrigado

Comment: Eu fiz um código de testes aqui, e ao que parece tudo roda nos conformes. 
Testei rapidamente no [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/c) e outro no [IDEONE] (https://ideone.com/n2n3G6). Eu criei uma função cria_no sem muita emoção, acredito ser algo próximo do que você quer.

O que estou achando estranho é que de fato o compilador não reclama do tipo da variável aqui, quando uso a função da forma errada. Como não tenho forma de passar parâmetros para o `gcc` (em especial o importantíssimo `-Wall`) no IDEONE, vou deixar como está. Chegando em casa, testo isso com mais cuidado.

Comment: Entendo, mas não era isso que eu queria. Acabei descobrindo aqui. é o tipo da função, se eu fazer uma função: `void insere (tipo_lista*p, tipo_lista*novo_no)` na `main`tenho que chamar `insere(&raiz_principal, cria_no(10));` entendeu?

Comment: Já se eu fizer uma função `tipo_lista * insere (tipo_lista *p, tipo_lista*novo_no)` na `main` eu devo chamar `raiz_principal = insere(raiz_principal, cria_no(0));`

Comment: Acho que na verdade é mais do que isso, pois quando você faz essas chamadas por referência (emulada), você na verdade trata estes parâmetros como se fossem retornos (no sentido de `return {alguma coisa}`).